# Compare SQL Server objects against TFS with SSDT?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, tfs, sql-server-data-tools

Is there a way to compare objects in SQL Server (tables, stored procedures, views) with their corresponding entries in Team Foundation Services, with SQL Server Data Tools?  I know it's possible with Visual Studio professional, but I don't see the same options with SSDT. IE, I can't create a SQL Server project in SSDT.

We currently use Red Gate's tools. Developers use RG's Source Control to move SQL Server objects from Dev to TFS. We use RG SQL Compare to compare the latest TFS entry for an object with our UAT.

I'm trying to do the same in SSDT with the TFS plug-in. Again, TFS check-in / check-out is possible, but I don't see how to interact with the database.

Is this possible or must we use Visual Studio Pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible or must we use Visual Studio Pro?

All the SQL Server tools ship in SSDT, and are free to [download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017) and install into an existing or new instance of Visual Studio 2017.  You should see a project template for "SQL Server Database Project"